# What is the head noun in 'the number of' phrases?

Tags: grammatical-number, relative-clauses, noun-phrases

What is the head noun in the noun phrase 'the number of koalas'? My concern is with the non-defining relative clause and the assignment of 'which' to one of the nouns in the NP.

My sentences read:

> 1. **The number** of koalas, which **are** native to Australia, **is** declining alarmingly.
> 2. **The number** of koalas, which **is** declining alarmingly, **needs** to be addressed by the authorities.

Are both correct?

Answer (score 3):

The head noun of "the number of Koalas" is "number", which is singular, and since it is head, it makes the entire noun phrase singular.  The relative clause "which are native to Australia" goes with the noun phrase "Koalas", and "which" refers to Koalas.  The relative clause "which is declining alarmingly" goes with the noun phrase "the number of Koalas", and "which" refers to that.  (I think that the relative pronoun of such nonrestrictive relative clauses refers to a noun phrase rather than to a noun.)

Yes, both are correct.